# How does GCP "Managing SSH keys in metadata" works behind the scenes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys, openssh

I understand the gcp provide a functionality where adding a ssh public key in instance meta  will allow user to ssh into the machine with publickey authentication.

**But, I am interested to know how gcp does that?**

Does GCP intercept by ssh request before it reaches the machine and add the relevant authorized_keys into my machine?
Or
Does SSH provide some functionality which is used by GCP to achieve such capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud runs software (guest agent) during a VM startup that copies SSH keys from the Metadata service to the VM. This includes creating home directories and setting up authorized_keys.

> On Linux: If OS Login is not used, the guest agent will be responsible
> for provisioning and deprovisioning user accounts. The agent creates
> local user accounts and maintains the authorized SSH keys file for
> each. User account creation is based on adding and remove SSH Keys
> stored in metadata.

This software is called the [Guest Environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment).

The source code is published on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-agent).